# Joomla3 - switch to responsive template -> 2nd featured article only half the width

Tags: templates, responsive, joomla3.5

We've switched from our old non responsive template to a new (but design-wise exactly the same) responsive one.

The problem is, that the second featured article on the main page (in our case "News") uses only half the width or even less.

[It should look like this (old template),](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQqUl.jpg)

[but it actually looks like this now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbbW7.jpg)

The url to the actual website is twilight-events.de
(sorry not allowed to post more than two links)

Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have a "blog view" of a category, or "featured articles".

In the menu link, you can edit how many column you want, how many fullpage (featured) articles you want on the top of the page, etc.

If it's in you homepage, check which menu entry is you homepage (it's starred).

Then play the options offered ;-)

[image: Blog category menu item: parameters]

Comment: Thanks for this very clear and extremely helpful answer.

It really did solve the problem, but I do not understand why this problem doesn't occur when using the non responsive template (without the option you mentioned).

I mean, there must be a way to change this inside the template.

Comment: Only suppositions here:
- Joomla use bootstrap2 as default, so the articles component (com_content) will output relevant classes (like _span12_ for full width, _span6_ for half..).
- your "non responsible" template may not offer the bootstrap base structure to make the columns work, or is blocking it on purpose (CSS overrides, etc)